# Personalization error: %%policy_number%%

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

> Personalization error: %%policy_number%% To fix the problem, please
> try the following: - Make sure that there is not a space or typo
> within the personalization string in your email. For example, check
> and correct any spaces between percent signs (%%) - Correct the
> Preheader of your email.

This is the exact error message I am getting. I already checked the Pre-header of my email and there is no spaces in between the characters.

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is policy_number a field in your sendable DE?

Comment: Also, you can't set content for preheader in the body of the email, as per [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321251&type=1)

Comment: To clarify what @LukasLunow is saying, you can set the preheader in the Email HTML Content of your Asset - It just has to be set above the HTML `<body>` tag in the raw HTML. Anything after the body tag will be ignored by the preheader input on your email definition.